# Is it possible to reorder columns in bootstrap 4 using size classe if only a single row is used?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm playing around with Bootstrap and considering using a single row and column wrapping for my design. The reason for this is because I want to reorder the elements depending on the screen size. Current code is as follows:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12 nav-bar">
      Navigation
    </div>

    <div class="col-12 header">
      Header
    </div>


    <div class="col-12 content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim
      adminim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
      ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
      voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
      mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
      adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
      magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
      laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
      pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 feature sign-up">
      Sign up
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 feature feature-1">
      Feature 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 feature feature-2">
      Feature 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 feature feature-3">
      Feature 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make the third column `content` the first column for the `lg` screen size? I see the order class lets you assign order based from 1-12. I tried using `<div class="col-12 content order-md-1">` but it made it the last element, not the first.

Comment: *but wondering if this will also work if only a single row is used.* --> did you try?

Comment: Sorry, yes I did, edited my question.

Comment: You need to make all the element after so the class need to be added to other element

Answer (score 0):

The following css will do the trick. 
You are basically implementing the order-first class manually but only for large screens

```
@media (min-width:1200px){
  .content{
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

heres a codepen you can play with 
https://codepen.io/mugwag/pen/VwvpNRV